# In Dart, how to pass a function as parameter that returns a Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass a function that returns `Future<Response>` as parameter of a method

I tried to do

```
Future<String> _execute(Function<Future<Response>>() function) async { }
```

but it does not even compile.

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
Future<String> _myFunction(Future<Response> Function() function) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Very hard to grasp parameter signature. Thank you for making it easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to specify that your parameter is a Function:

```dart
Future<bool> kappa() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return true;
}
​
Future<bool> foo(Function f) async{
  var k = await f();
  return k;
}
​
void main() async{
   print(await foo(kappa));
}
```

This will print `true`. In your case, your function parameter can be:

```dart
Future<String> _execute(Function function) async { }
```

Comment: with this, when you want to add the return type, the thing fails you very badly